# Reload Table Animation

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-animation

So when a user taps on a cell in my table I don't actually push to a new view controller I just reload the data inside of that tableView.

However, I want to get an effect simular to what it would look like if I did push a new view controller.

Does anybody know how I can slide old content off old content off the screen and new content onto the screen for an entire table?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Depending on how many sections you have you can use `- (void)reloadSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation`

So you could do something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    [tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0,[self numberOfSectionsInTableView])] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
}
```

Comment: The app crashes if I load data with a different amount of sections.I think i'm just going to insert a second tableview and slide it over the old one.

Comment: do you know how many sections you will always have? if so the NSMakeRange is the range of sections that it will reload, so start at 0 (the first arg) and then put in the length for the second arg

Comment: No it is all being pulled down from a server and being dynamically parsed.

Comment: i mean when they select a cell, do you have some way of determining the current number of sections?

Comment: DanZimm : I have the same problem. Did you figure out a way to do this gracefully without having to know before/after the differences in sections?

Answer (score 0):

Simple animation

```
    func animateTable() {
    self.reloadData()

    let cells = self.visibleCells
    let tableHeight: CGFloat = self.bounds.size.height

    for i in cells {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = i as UITableViewCell
        cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: tableHeight)
    }

    var index = 0

    for a in cells {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = a as UITableViewCell

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 0.05 * Double(index), usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveLinear, animations: {
            cell.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }, completion: nil)

        index += 1
    }
}
```